# Why can't I print from background threads in Clojure Cider REPL in emacs?

Tags: emacs, clojure, stdout, read-eval-print-loop, cider

If I try to evaluate the following code in my emacs cider-repl, nil is returned, as expected, but none of the printing takes place in the repl buffer or console. How can I make this print out as intended?

```
(dotimes [i 5]                                                                                                                                        
  (.start                                                                                                                                             
   (Thread.                                                                                                                                           
    (fn []                                                                                                                                             
      (Thread/sleep (rand 500))                                                                                                                       
      (println (format "Finished %d on %s" i (Thread/currentThread)))))))
;=> nil
```

This works fine, however:

```
(println (format "Finished 1 on %s" (Thread/currentThread)))
;=> Finished 1 on Thread[nREPL-worker-18,5,main]
----------- mini-buffer -----------------
nil
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The behavior of `println` is to use a dynamically bound var called `*out*` as its output stream. emacs dynamically binds `*out*` to go to the repl buffer for code evaluated in the repl buffer, but if you create a thread, that thread's `*out*` gets the root binding of `*out*`, which in the case of cider will not be the repl buffer.

If you started the repl using `cider-jack-in`, when you look at you buffer list there should be a buffer with a name like `*nrepl-server*` which contains the output of the root `*out*` binding. Here is the contents of mine after running your code:

```
nREPL server started on port 52034 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:52034
Finished 1 on Thread[Thread-9,5,main]
Finished 0 on Thread[Thread-8,5,main]
Finished 2 on Thread[Thread-10,5,main]
Finished 3 on Thread[Thread-11,5,main]
Finished 4 on Thread[Thread-12,5,main]
```

If you did not use `cider-jack-in`, the output will print to the terminal where you started the nrepl process.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solves the mystery and you just taught me something about both Clojure and Emacs. Is there some way I could rebind the *out* variable for background threads to also print out to the repl buffer?

Comment: `*out*` can be set with `binding`, as any other dynamic var can. @amalloy's answer does a good job of showing that part I think.

Answer (score 11):

`*out*` is the dynamic variable determining where output from `println` and similar functions goes. It is *thread-bound* to someplace that causes stuff to be sent back to emacs for display by cider; if you start a new thread, that binding is not present, and the output goes elsewhere (probably to the stdout of the nrepl server emacs/leiningen started in the background).

You can address this in a few ways. You could capture the value of `*out*` from the parent thread, and then pass it along to the child thread in a closure, and rebind `*out*` to it:

```
(let [out *out*] 
  (.start (Thread. (fn [] 
                     (binding [*out* out]
                        (println "test"))))))
```

Or you can use a `future` instead of starting the thread yourself: Clojure automatically conveys relevant thread-local bindings to new threads started for a future.

Comment: Hey man, could you show me a code example using future? I played around with it at the repl, but I couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: (future (println "test"))

Answer (score 8):

Execute the following expression in the repl, then all output will end up in the repl:

```
(alter-var-root #'*out* (constantly *out*))
```

original answer:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cider-emacs/bIVBvRnGO-U/nDszDbGoVzgJ

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Figwheel, then doing prn/println in ring handlers (which are actually similar to the Threads example shown above) can also be swallowed by Fighweel itself. Check your project's project.clj (look for the key :server-logfile inside the :figwheel map), where you can control if *out* should go to the repl or to a logfile. Please note, this only applies if you are using figwheel, otherwise the printing to the REPL of course works fine.

See my answer on this question for more details: [Output compojure server print statements into figwheel terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859079/output-compojure-server-print-statements-into-figwheel-terminal/44784737#44784737)