# Clojure rebinding *out* for JavaFX UI elements

Tags: clojure, javafx

I'm trying to get `println` to output to an arbitrary location, either on the emacs-cider repl or to a JavaFX TextArea.  I've referenced [Why can't I print from background threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743958/why-cant-i-print-from-background-threads-in-clojure-cider-repl-in-emacs) and this has allowed me to do `println` from within the JavaFX thread by rebinding `*out*` to that of the starting thread.

However this doesn't work when the `println` is called from a `ChangeListener`, whether created outside or inside the JFX thread.

In the text below I have two `TextField`s, one created in the main thread, one created in the JFX Thread, as well as two instances of ChangeListener, one as a `defstruct` which implements the interface, and another as a `reify`, both instantiated from within the JFX thread.

Each time I type a character in either of the two `TextField`s, the responding text shows up in the original thread's `*out*` stream.

How do I fix this so all `println`s find the correct `*out*` as intended?
thanks

```
(ns junk.core
  (:gen-class )
  (:use jfxutils.core)
  (:import (javafx.beans.value ObservableValue ChangeListener)
           (javafx.stage Stage)
           (javafx.scene Scene)
           (javafx.scene.control TextArea TextField)
           (javafx.scene.layout VBox)
           (java.io PrintStream PrintWriter)))


(defn make-vbox-scene [& items]
  (let [vb (VBox.)
        scene (Scene. vb)]
    (apply add-to-children vb items)
    scene))

(defn make-window [scene & [width height]]
  (let [stage (Stage.)]
    (.setScene stage scene)
    (when width (.setWidth stage width))
    (when height (.setHeight stage height))
    stage))


(defrecord myobservable []
  ChangeListener
  (^void changed [this ^ObservableValue obsval oldval newval]
    ;; This println goes to the original *out* stream
    (println "Myobservable thread" (Thread/currentThread) ", *out* is " *out*)))


(def text1 (TextField. "hi")) ;; Created in main thread


(defn -start [myout]
  ;; Everything here is in JFX thread
  (println "JFX thread is " (Thread/currentThread) ",JFX *out* is " *out*)
  (binding [*out* myout] ;; only works for obvious/direct println, not from UI
    (let [myobs (myobservable.) ;; Created in JFX thread
          text2 (TextField. "bye") ;; Created in JFX thread
          vbscene1 (make-vbox-scene text1 text2)
          window1 (make-window vbscene1)]

      ;; This println works!  Output goes to cider-repl or other PrintWriter pointed to by myout.
      (println "After rebinding out, thread is " (Thread/currentThread) "*out* is " *out*)

      ;; These printlns go to the original *out* stream in the *nrepl-server junk* buffer, not cider
      ;; This means I also can't reassign the myout arg to some other PrintWriter
      (-> text1 .textProperty (.addListener myobs))
      (-> text1 .textProperty (.addListener (reify ChangeListener
                                              (changed [this obsval oldval newval]
                                                (println "Anonymous listener 1, thread is " (Thread/currentThread) "*out* is " *out*)))))
      (-> text2 .textProperty (.addListener myobs))
      (-> text2 .textProperty (.addListener (reify ChangeListener
                                              (changed [this obsval oldval newval]
                                                (println "Anonymous listener 2, thread is " (Thread/currentThread) "*out* is " *out*)))))
      (.show window1))))

(defn main []
  (println "main thread is " (Thread/currentThread) ", *out* is " *out*)
  (run-now (-start *out*)))

(defn -main []
  (javafx.application.Platform/setImplicitExit true) ;; Undoes false from jfxutils
  (main))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried altering the var root of *out*? e.g.

```
(alter-var-root #'*out* (constantly *out*))
```

using `binding` will resolve the var to the bound value only for the current thread.

Other threads will continue to see the root value of the var, unless `binding` is used within those threads as well.

The callbacks (e.g. ChangeListener) are invoked from threads that are not under your control and therefore have no per-thread bindings. They will resolve the root value of the var.

You have to therefore alter the root value of *out* in order for those threads to resolve the value that you wish.

There is more information available on var bindings [here](http://clojure.org/vars).

Comment: Actually, it worked for the first text field `alter`ing `*out*` to `(constantly *out*)` or to another `PrintWriter`, but for the second text field it only worked for `alter`ing `*out*` to `(constantly  *out*`)` but not to another PW, presumably having to do with what thread the PW was created in.  I'm just kind of shooting in the dark here.  I need to study this better. thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a short description of why this works. You only have to alter the root binding once and do not have to call it in every thread that you instantiate. I can not see the modifications that you made in your code after adding alter-var-root, but I would guess that you are attempting to invoke it in every thread rather than just binding it once to the desired value.