# clojure cider repl in emacs cant print from core async callback

Tags: emacs, clojure

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743958/why-cant-i-print-from-background-threads-in-clojure-cider-repl-in-emacs) but it doesn't work.

```
(require '[clojure.core.async :as a])
(def ch2 (a/chan))
(defn my-take [] (a/take! ch2 (fn [v] (println v) (my-take))))
(a/put! ch2 "value" (fn (if [success?] (println "success"))))
```

This code on a `lein repl` works as expected. But on `*cider repl*` it doesn't print the `println` statements.

And I don't see any output on `*nrepl-server*` buffer either.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what's your CIDER version, but in the upcoming 0.10 we've added some functionality that forwards the nREPL server output to the same place the regular output goes (by default the REPL buffer). 
You can install the snapshot and see if this solves your issue.

P.S. Typically it's best to ask questions like this on our official gitter and slack channels. Posting tickets in GitHub is also a good idea.