# Output compojure server print statements into figwheel terminal?

Tags: clojure, compojure

Where does `pprint`/`println` output go in compojure?/Can I get it to show up in the terminal window that the figwheel repl is running in? (Sorry if this sounds dumb, google bested my efforts).

Comment: I'm new to Clojure myself but usually figwheel is for using with front-end clojurescript and Compojure is used for backend Clojure for the server. If I'm understanding it seems a little odd to have them interact directly.

Comment: I thought because `lein figwheel` spun up the backend as well it would be the reasonable place to output server logging to. Basically I'm looking for how to do print-debugging with the server side of a compojure app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Figwheel has a related feature to cause such symptoms. All print/prn statements in your ring handlers will be "swallowed" by the Figwheel process and will either go to a log file or to the console.

Here is a snippet from project.clj:

```
 :figwheel
  {:http-server-root "public"
   :server-port 3449
   :nrepl-port 7002
   :css-dirs ["resources/public/css"]
   :ring-handler myapp.handler/app
   :server-logfile false
   }
```

The key :server-logfile is controlling this behavior. If it's false, then *out* is your regular repl console, if it's a filename, then anything printed will go to that file (if it's not present, then the default is using file "figwheel_server.log".

Figwheel issue:
https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/issues/436
Figwheel commit: https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/commit/330d8d7fda8be145615910cf639bd9a3242339ba

Answer (score 1):

It seems to show up there without any special setup... I get this at the console:

```
Prompt will show when Figwheel connects to your application
"I got a request"
```

Triggering the handler:

```
curl localhost:3449/foo
```

src/with_server/server.clj

```
(ns with-server.server)

(defn handler [req]
  (prn "I got a request")
  {})
```

In project.clj under :figwheel {}

```
:ring-handler with-server.server/handler
```

If you are having trouble, maybe you need ring-reload middleware so that the changes you are making get reloaded?

Comment: unexpected behavior was stopping my code from getting to the prn statement. *facepalm*